# Multiple declarations of "BExp"

Tags: haskell

I have the following data structure:

`data BExp = BConst Bool | Not BExp | BExp And BExp | BExp Or BExp`

(deriving Eq and Show)

which defines a boolean expression, but whenever I compile I get the following error:

`Multiple declarations of 'BExp'
 Declared at: PData.hs:9:38
             PData.hs:9:54`

I have only defined it once and nowhere else in my file.

Comment: You can write `data BExp = BConst Bool | Not BExp | BExp ``And`` BExp | BExp ``Or`` BExp`. Backticks can turn ordinary names into infix operators. _Use single backticks where I have double ones - I couldn't figure out how to get Markdown show single backticks._

Comment: Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `BExp` constructors defined, just like the compiler says:

```hs
data BExp = BConst Bool | Not BExp | BExp And BExp | BExp Or BExp
                                     ^               ^
                                     |               |
                                    Here         ... and here
```

One of those will need to change to a new constructor name.

**edit**

Based on your comment, you really want to use `And` and `Or` as the constructor names, like this:

```hs
data BExp = BConst Bool | Not BExp | And BExp BExp | Or BExp BExp
```

You can then use them as infix functions as follows:

```hs
someBExp = (BConst True) `And` (BConst False)
```

Comment: So if I write those 2 like this: `And BExp BExp` It should be solved?

Comment: Yes; in that case your constructor name is `And` (and `Or`, assuming you change it as well)

Comment: You can also leave your constructors in infix position by enclosing them in backticks.

Comment: You could even name them `:&&` and `:||` instead, so that infix is their natural position.